# How to do an arbitrarily structured sparse checkout

Tags: svn, sparse-checkout

I have a project with a directory structure like this:

```
project
|--source
|--fgh
|--...
|--ijk
`--tests
   |--abc
   |--cde
   |--...
   |--utils
```

I want to checkout the `source` and `tests/utils` directories (and everything inside recursively). Remainder directories (like `abc`, `cde`, ...) should not be checked out since they are huge.

I think `svn co --depth empty` is what I'm looking for. But then how to check out only `tests/utils` if `test` doesn't exist after the checkout is done?

Comment: JFYI: Dry theory from [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html) ("how and why?")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track - do it like this:

```
svn co [REPO-URL] --depth emtpy
svn up [PROJECT]/source --depth infinity
svn up [PROJECT]/tests --depth empty
svn up [PROJECT]/tests/utils --depth infinity
```

**Edit:** [LazyBadger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/960558/lazy-badger) is arguing that "`--set-depth` for `svn up` will be more correct way". Well, the SVN [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html) quite clearly states for the `--set-depth` option (emphasis mine):

> It is with this option that you can **change** the sticky depth of a working copy item.

However in this case, we are not changing any previously checked out working copy item - We're building a (sparse) working copy from scratch, step by step. So why would `--set-depth` be more correct? It isn't. But for completeness, if you'd like to type a bit more, you could also do:

```
svn co [REPO-URL] --depth emtpy
svn up [PROJECT]/source --set-depth infinity
svn up [PROJECT]/tests --set-depth empty
svn up [PROJECT]/tests/utils --set-depth infinity
```

Comment: But, well, `--set-depth` for `svn up` will be more correct way

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the `svn up [PROJECT]/tests --depth empty` bit was missing in my approach. But now it seems to be logical.